# How can i decrease the time it takes foe my program to send requests?

Tags: c#, request

im trying to make a name sniper and I have made it send requests at a  specific time but i am still running into some problems. Here is my code  for reference (Bearer token is invalid on purpose):

```
using System.Net;
using System.Text;

namespace HudProjects
{
    static class Program
    {
        public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("[Ender]Enter Name >> ");
            string name = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("[Ender]Enter DropTime >> ");
            var Unixtime = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("[Ender]Enter Offset >> ");
            var offset = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            var epoch = Convert.ToInt64(Unixtime);
            var time = Convert.ToInt64(DateTimeOffset.Now.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds());
            var droptime = Convert.ToInt32(epoch - time);
            Client Client = new Client();
            Thread.Sleep(droptime - offset);
            while (true)
            {
                var sent = DateTimeOffset.Now.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds();
                await SnipeAsync(name, Client);
                Console.Write($"  Sent:  + {sent}");
            }

        }

        public static async Task SnipeAsync(string name, Client client)
        {
            await client.Put(name);
        }



    }

    public class Client
    {
        private readonly HttpClient _client;

        public Client()
        {
            _client = new HttpClient();
        }

        public async Task Put(string name)
        {
            using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Put, $"https://api.minecraftservices.com/minecraft/profile/name/{name}"))
            {
                request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ4dWlkIjoiMjUzNTQyMDgxMzA3MzgzNSIsImFnZyI6IkFkdWx0Iiwic3ViIjoiMDhiMWJjNmItYTlkMS00YjU1LWI2YzktY2Q5NTFlM2Q1OGY1IiwibmJmIjoxNjU3MjgwNzU4LCJhdXRoIjoiWEJPWCIsInJvbGVzIjpbXSwiaXNzIjoiYXV0aGVudGljYXRpb24iLCJleHAiOjE2NTczNjcxNTgsImlhdCI6MTY1NzI4MDc1OCwicGxhdGZvcm0iOiJVTktOT1dOIiwieXVpZCI6IjFlNTM4M2Y2MWI5ZTllMTNkMTJiMmM0MmVlNGIyNjJlIn0.IiWo2PPNsow0_olRHTJnBYwbhRrga9LHp9-ZQL_K46M");
                using (var response = await _client.SendAsync(request))
                {

                    Console.WriteLine($"Status Code:  {response.StatusCode}");

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is a test to show the results

[Ender]Enter Name >> asd

[Ender]Enter DropTime >> 1657444560000

[Ender]Enter Offset >> 200

Status Code: Unauthorized Sent: + 1657444560001

Status Code: Unauthorized Sent: + 1657444560653

Status Code: Unauthorized Sent: + 1657444560781

Status Code: Unauthorized Sent: + 1657444560878

Status Code: Unauthorized Sent: + 1657444560980

Status Code: Unauthorized Sent: + 1657444561148

Is there any way to make my program send the requests quicker?(keep in mind I don't need to wait for a request to be recieved before sending another one)

Answer (score 0):

You can start all requests at the same time and wait from them later, like this...

```
            const int batchSize = 64;
            List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>(batchSize);
            for (int i = 0; i < batchSize; i++)
            {
                Task task = SnipeAsync(name, client);
                tasks.Add(task);
            }
            // wait for all tasks to be done
            await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Comment: Note that `HttpClient` will create multiple connections to the server, each of which will take time to connect, but you will have to read the response (I think Dispose will read it for you?) before each connection can be reused.